# find rows with column C not in list of values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Table "*A*":

| id | name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | cat1 |
| 2 | bar | cat2 |
| 3 | foob | cat1 |
| 4 | booh | cat999 |

Table "*B*":

| id | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1, cat3 |
| 2 | cat2, cat1, cat3 |
| 3 | cat1 |

I'd like to find rows of table "*A*" with `A.category_id NOT IN B.categories`. As you see, the problem is "*B.categories*" are comma separated values, I don't see how to use "*LIKE*" in such case.

In my example I must be able to find row #4 of table "*A*".

Comment: I know title is not too clear, but I didn't found a better one ... sorry :(

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and for the where clause you can use FIND_IN_SET

Comment: I would strongly suggest you normalize the database design to 1NF at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `NOT EXISTS` with `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM B b
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.category_id, b.categories)
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b7ed98e81661f8f04e7893792ccba141)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FIND_IN_SET` function to check the existence of a category in your categories string, join the two tables and filter out non null values:

```
SELECT A.category_id
FROM      A
LEFT JOIN B
       ON FIND_IN_SET(A.category_id, B.categories)
WHERE B.categories IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fFENJmxfWpq7WrKVYmHCaN/0).

Comment: this also works :)